# Incoming Email Service with multiple frontend server

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, incoming-email, smtp, front-end

I am running **SharePoint 2013 foundation** with ***two frontend servers***. I have this `Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Incoming Email` Job started on both frontends(say FE1 and FE2).

Now my SMTP is configured on FE1 and when i send mails they are dumped to Drop folder of my FE1, while my Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Incoming Email Job is running for FE2.But neither my Incoming or Outgoing mails are working. The incoming ones are routed to Drop folder of FE1 but SharePoint Job doesn't pick them

So i want to know that if it is necessary that even Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Incoming Email Job to run on FE1 ? if yes how to i configure it to run on FE1 instead of FE2

Answer (score 0):

`Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Incoming Email` is required on the WFE your have the SMTP service running on, i.e. FE1. You can start/stop this service per server from CA, "System Settings" and "Services on Server" (select the targetted server in the drop-dpwn list at the top of the page).

That server (FE1) must be the one your Exchange/Mail server realys SharePoint incoming mails to.

Comment: I already have Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Incoming Email running on my FE1(here SMTP is configured) as well as FE2 but when i check Job History it shows that it has succeeded on FE2 but not for FE1. any reason for such behaviour? Job History shows it  hasn't executed for FE1

Comment: Can you try to stop it on FE2?

Comment: Thanks but, tried stopping it on FE2 restarted it on FE1 restarted SP Timer service on FE1, Tried running Email job manually on FE1 but it still doesn't run, neither it is visible in Job History nor Running job not even under Scheduled Job, any other ways that can help me?